# Como tomar datos de unos input text y enviarlos a mysql en java REST

Tags: java, rest

Yo tengo esto mismo hecho en `Servlets`, un `index.jsp` donde estan los inputs, una clase de conexión, otra que procesa la subida y el `servlet`, sin embargo me estoy insertando en los servicios REST, mi objetivo es subir datos a una base de datos mysql y realizar consultas (ahora con REST y evitar los Servlets).

Mis pasos hasta ahora fueron estos:

1) Creé una clase con el `@GET`, `@Path`, etc, el cual funciona con las librerías jersey y jsr 311.

2) El xml.

3) Creé una clase de conexión.

4) Creé una clase llamada Persona donde van los setters & getters, como nombre y apéllido.

5) Estoy creando una clase que lleva como parámetros la clase persona para poder acceder a ella y que se inserten.

Sin embargo usando los Servlets lo entiendo mejor porque uso `request.getParameter("inputDelHTML");`

No sé que usar procesar la info y enviarla a la DB. EL archivo con el `@GET` anda muy bien, me imagino que con el `@POST` también funcionará bien, sin embargo estoy trabado y con otras consultas.

---

Preguntas generales:

a) Cómo tomo ése dato de un input en un html y lo envío a la DB?(Como lo hacía con los Servlets)

b) Me estoy equivocando en el concepto?

c)Estoy obligado a usar `@PathParam`, `@QueryParam`, `@FormParam`? (necesito sinceridad porque no me molestaría cambiar sólo me tengo que acostumbrar).

d)En general cuando se crea un servicio REST en java se usa un archivo html o un jsp? consulto porque en una clase sistemas que tuve no tocaron el jsp, cuando pregunté porqué eligieron html y no jsp aludieron a que "trae confusiones", esta pregunta es de absoluta ignorancia mía.

---

Actualización, porqué apesar de que me funcionen las variable en el return del fondo, no funcionan dentro de la función insert que abajo describo? si la dejo sin variables funciona excelente, intenté revisar las comillas y no encuentro el error. Eclipse tampoco me marca un error al momento de incluir esas variables dentro del try / if, ya que no me tira error y le cambia el color inclusive, pero funcionan.

```
    @POST
    @Path("/insertarEmpleado")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String insertarEmpleado(@FormParam("usuario") String usuario , @FormParam("pass") String pass ){

        try
            {

            ConexionAeropuerto c= new ConexionAeropuerto();
            Connection con= c.connectarAhora();

            if(con!=null)
                    {
                        Statement st;
                        st=con.createStatement();

                        //Esta de acá es la que quiero que me funcione y no lo hace, la consulta no se realiza, por más que haya revisado todo no encuentro la solución, revisé comillas etc.

                        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO empleados(usuario,pass) VALUES('" + usuario + "','" + pass + ")'");

                        //Esta consulta comentada acá abajo se inserta perfectamente al localhost, pero sólo si la dejo lisa y sin variables)
                        //st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO empleados(usuario,pass) VALUES('des','mo')");
                        st.close(); 
                    } 
            else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Algo Salió mal no se pudo insertar los datos");
                    }
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 

                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            //Este de acá funciona excelente imprime las variable tal cual.
            return "<html>" + "<body><h3>" + "El nombre del empleado es: "  + usuario + "<br>"+ "El apellido del empleado es: " + pass + "</h3></body>" + "</html>";

        }
```

Comment: Hola berlot, 
creo que te puedo ayudar solo con una parte, A) para el envió de datos puedes usar 2 vías, poner tus input en un form y en el action pones el nombre de tu servlet y dentro del form coloca un botón tipo submit, la segunda opcion es usar ajax para hacer la petición.
y en el inciso D) puedes usar ambos, la diferencia es que con un jsp puedes embeber código java, mientras que en html no lo puedes hacer. Espero te ayude en algo.  Saludos

Comment: Realmente lo que quiero hacer es lo mismo que decís vos, pero en REST, ése es el problema, porque lo sé hacer en un servlet pero no con REST. No le encuentro solución realmente.

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo conceptos. Sería mejor que muestres el código que permita reflejar lo que estás haciendo y te ayudamos sobre esa base.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza arriba subi el código, traté de explayarme lo mejor posible, si quieren editenlo, entendí cómo pasar de un input text html a POST por medio de FormParam, pero cuando quiero insertar una consulta a mi DB no lo hace con las variables, pero sin las variables sí.

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis del query esta mal:
La comilla que cierra esta fuera del parentesis y deberia de estar adentro.

```
//Incorrecto
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO empleados(usuario,pass) VALUES('" + usuario + "','" + pass + ")'");
```

Deberia ser:

```
//Correcto
    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO empleados(usuario,pass) VALUES('" + usuario + "','" + pass + "')");
```

Por otro lado es muy mala practica usar `con.createStatement` has escuchado hacerca de SQLInjection? [sql injection](https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-using-prepared-callable-statement)
Concatenar variables directamente en el query es un riesgo muy grande.

Te recomiendo usar preparedStatement:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO empleados(usuario,pass) VALUES(?,?)");
stmt.setString(1, usuario);
stmt.setString(2, pass);
int cant = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Ademas te dejo un buen link donde habla de servicios rest con jersey [jersey docs](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html)